# Skype silent chat message

Tags: skype

Reason: I have a contact that I know is busy, but still want notifications so he is in "online"-mode and not DND-mode. I want to write "OK" to him, without having to disturb him (having him to open and look in skype to see if it was something important, which it is not).

Question: Is there any way to send a message that won't trigger a notification at the receiver's end? Something like a "silent message".

Comment: Probably not. But receiving a message will not disturb him a lot given that the content of the message is displayed in the notification. He will not have to do anything to see that the message is not important (at least this is how it works on Linux, it would be surprising if it was Linux-specific)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit backwards, but you can have the other side use the Skype command `/alertson OK`, within the required chat window.

This will cause Skype to only notify them of messages containing the word "OK".

Just make sure the other side doesn't forget to turn it off with `/alertsoff` when you're done.